# JAVAFX non-latin character

Tags: java-8, javafx-8, java

I'm build a javafx installer with inno setup and link ".test" files to my soft.
but if i create a file,if the file name with non-Latin characters(中国.test) will cause JVM exception.
i don't know why?
double click the file "中国.test":
[image]

after click ok:
[image]

my environment:

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)
```

Thanks!

Comment: For others: this SO-question resulted [from some reported bug of the javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/209), seems to be windows-specific, application itself is working with latin-char-filenames.